# convention regarding offline temporary data

Tags: directory-structure

When writing small utility programs, I sometimes want to keep small amounts of data around *between* executions, usually for caching purposes, but don't want the program to run as a daemon. Are there any conventions regarding this? Making files in `/tmp` seems obvious, as it is usually kept in memory, and is only wiped at shutdown, but I'm curious if there are other ways. Also, is there a convention for naming files in `/tmp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the program is installed by a system administrator, and it's ok if the data is erased now and then, create a directory under [`/var/cache`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARCACHEAPPLICATIONCACHEDATA). Files under `/var/cache` can be deleted by the system administrator at any time, but normally aren't unless the system is running out of disk space. Managing `/var/cache/YOUR-DIRECTORY` so that it doesn't grow out of control is your application's responsibility.

If the program is installed by a system administrator, and the data must never be erased without your application's control, create a directory under [`/var/lib`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION).

Don't use `/tmp` for that: it can (and often is) wiped on reboot. `/tmp` is only for data that is not kept between separate invocations of an application. Don't use `/var/tmp` either: although it usually isn't erased on reboot, the system administrator may choose to wipe it at any time.

If your application is executed by individual users and each have their own data set, then the files must be in the user's home directory. There is no traditional Unix standard for organizing files in a user's home directory, other than the convention to use a [file whose name begins with a `.` (“dot file”)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_file). There is a modern standard, the [XDG](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) FreeDesktop specification. For cache data (which can be wiped without impacting anything but performance), create a directory under `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`, defaulting to `~/.cache`. For application data, create a directory under `$XDG_DATA_HOME`, defaulting to `~/.local/share`, or directly under the home directory (and in this case beginning with `.`).

Comment: For cache that is inherently invalid after a shutdown, would /tmp make sense over /var/cache?

Comment: Also, if the program is not supposed to be run as root, is /tmp the best place?

Comment: are there conventions regarding naming of `YOUR-DIRECTORY`, e.g. to make sure there are no naming collisions?

Comment: @Abdull The convention is to use the name of your application. That's typically the same name that you'd use as a directory name in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/share`, as a package name for package managers, etc. If your application is a single executable that's the name you'd use for the executable in `/usr/bin` too. There's no convention to use naming hierarchies like there is e.g. for Android apps with domain names.

Answer (score 2):

There's also `/run`, but the convention seems to be that while `/tmp` is world writable, `/run` requires root privileges.  `/var` has similar restrictions.

So your best bet is either `/tmp`, or something you arrange via configuration (so that the user can specify a runtime directory).

WRT to naming conventions, it appears to be a free-for-all global space -- use whatever identifiers you want, following the common sense principle that `/tmp/stuff` is probably not a good idea as there is an increased potential for it to get stomped on by someone with similarly brilliant ideas.

I notice some applications use a java-esque domain based namespace, e.g `.com.google.Chrome`.  It does not matter as long as it is unique and makes enough sense to whomever it must make sense to.  Bonus points if it also provides some clue to others as to where it came from.

Comment: I've accepted Gilles answer, because it seems more general, but I appreciate you answering the part about naming conventions, thanks!